# Why do some AC adapters and power supplies generate a whining noise, and what can I do about it?

Tags: power-supply, noise, charger, community-faq-proposed

I have many different AC adapters and power supplies for a variety of devices, ranging from small 5V/1A USB chargers to laptop power adapters and desktop PSUs. However, I often hear a whining noise from  some of these power supplies. This happens most often when they are not connected to a device or otherwise in use, and stop making noise when I connect a load to it such as by plugging in a device that is not fully charged.

Why do some AC adapters and power supplies make this whining noise? Why do some *not* make this noise? Is there anything I can do to suppress it?

Comment: It sounds some of these chargers are just cheap, the noise, means their output isn't "clean"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostriction, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coil_noise (I'll be writing a full answer shortly)

Comment: I've edited the question to expand the scope to computer power supplies to ensure that it is on topic for Super User.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before.  Most recent in memory is [here](http://superuser.com/questions/784986/psu-noise-when-turned-off/).

Comment: The whine is usually because the minimum amount of electrical current is not being drawn from the (switched mode) power supply.  When *"plugged in but not connected to a device"*, zero current (and power) is drawn from the AC adapter simply because there is no load attached to the power supply.  Switched mode power supplies do not operate efficiently with small or no electrical loads.  See other comments & answers for the mechanical details.

Comment: @Ramhound Audible noise from a power supply does not imply noise in the electrical output.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I have a different personal experience;

Comment: @Jason: I'm making this the canonical question. I've voted to close as duplicate on the question you've linked to and tagged this question [community-faq-proposed].

Comment: @DragonLord I appreciate that, but this is a poor question to pick.  AC adapters for "gadgets" aren't computer hardware, which makes this off-topic.

Comment: @Jason: I've rewritten the post to further broaden the topic area and give equal weight to computer power supplies.

Comment: @DragonLord If this is to be canonical, can we totally hijack the question?  High frequency noise in computers caused by vibrating coils is just as commonly caused by motherboards and video cards.

Comment: When I first got my desktop it had this problem (actually I asked about it [here](http://superuser.com/questions/443872/my-power-supply-whines-is-there-anything-i-can-do-about-it?noredirect=1#comment1094053_443872)). I found after time it went away by itself. Also it was normally only audible when the computer was first powered on or powered off. It was damn annoying, as the pitch varried.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Most power conversion devices contains coils, such as transformers or inductors. These components use electromagnetism to convert AC mains power to low-voltage DC power. The varying magnetic fields generated by these components can cause them to physically vibrate at high frequency, resulting in a high-pitched noise.

Most modern AC adapters are [switched-mode power supplies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply). The internal switching frequency of an SMPS is typically low when unloaded and increases with load up to a certain point depending on the design. The no-load frequency is often low enough to be within the human hearing range. In addition, in low or no-load situations, the [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) used to regulate voltage at the [inverter stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply#Inverter_stage) will be at a low duty cycle creating a "spikey" output profile which is more prone to causing vibration in coils, and the transformer itself will tend to vibrate as well (see Daniel R Hick's answer below for more details). Together, these can lead to audible noise especially in cheaper units which fail to suppress this noise.

Under load, a properly functioning SMPS should operate at a frequency well above the human hearing range, typically 50 kHz or higher (although some older designs operate at 33 kHz). However, the same noise can occur under load with a poorly designed or defective power supply as the coils may vibrate under electrical stress at a [subharmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic) frequency.

Coils used as inductors or transformers in other electronic devices, including those on motherboards, graphics cards, or other computer components, can also vibrate during operation. As such, a defective device can generate audible coil whine during operation.

This is why you sometimes see weird gobs of glue on coils inside electronic devices. The glue helps reduce the vibration and noise the coils generate during normal operation. It is entirely possible for users to apply glue onto coils using a glue gun to suppress coil whine, and people have successfully done so on their computer parts. However, you generally can't do this easily on small wall chargers of the sort you mentioned without risking damage to the charger or exposure to potentially dangerous voltages.

Ultimately, a whining noise isn't necessarily a sign of trouble in cheaper wall chargers when little or no power is being drawn from them. However, a computer PSU or laptop charger that generates coil noise especially when under load may be defective and you may want to consider replacing it.

More information on coil noise can be found in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coil_noise).

[image: Glue on SMD inductor]

Comment: You need to elaborate on the *"unloaded power supply"* aspect, and how that correlates to the OP's observations.

Comment: @sawdust: I'm not too familiar with how switched-mode power supplies work, so I'll need some time to research the topic.

Comment: No, I was not asking for technical details.  I meant that the phrase  *"unloaded power supply"* could mean nothing to a layperson.  "Unloaded" is what happens when *"plugged in but not connected to a device"*.

Comment: Your first sentence isn't [quite true](http://www.google.com/patents/US6353546), but close enough!

Comment: It's totally clear for me now. Thank you for a thorough explanation. It seems that each AC, despite most are from the similar products, has assembly flaws that causes its whining. The question itself was about why do coils cause whining, and now I see what happens that is the source of the sound.

Comment: @JasonC: Addressed.

Answer (score 17):

A "switching" power supply (like virtually all modern computer power supplies) works by "rectifying" the incoming 120V 60Hz (in the US) AC power into DC (at around 170 volts), "filtering" with capacitors, then using a semiconductor circuit to "chop" the DC voltage around 1000 times a second to turn it back into crude AC.  (What's referred to as a "square wave", vs the "sine wave" of ordinary AC.)  This "chopped" voltage then runs through a transformer to produce the desired output voltages.  The outputs are again rectified to DC and filtered, to produce the desired voltages for the computer.

With this scheme, basic voltage regulation is performed by adjusting the "duty cycle" of the chopped voltage.  When the power supply is lightly loaded the circuitry doesn't produce a nice symmetrical "square wave" but instead a series of narrow spikes, and that "spikey" waveform is more likely to produce annoying audible noise in the transformers and other components and is also more likely to produce "electrical noise" that you would, eg, hear in a nearby radio.

Additionally, when a power supply is lightly loaded more of the magnetic field inside a transformer escapes to the case of the transformer and to surrounding components (since less is captured by the "secondary" coil of the transformer), and this "escaping" magnetic field is more apt to cause noise.

Answer (score 8):

The transformers are created in part by gluing plates of metal together.  The AC fields causes back and forth forces in the metal plates.  As the transformer ages the plates begin to separate and allows for movement on the plates which vibrate causing the humming sound you hear.

Comment: Loose windings on transformers can also cause whine. Corsair tries to mitigate this issue through tighter QC on the transformers, rejecting those with overly loose windings. http://www.corsair.com/en-us/blog/2013/september/coil-whine

Comment: A coil of copper wire, without any "core" metal plates, can be made to whine.  As the magnetic field increases and decreases (generally about a thousand times a second) the force of the field causes the dimensions of the coil to change slightly, and this vibration leads to whine.  Even the wires on a printed circuit board can whine (slightly) under the right circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there anything I can do to suppress it?

As they've already told you, glue, because

1. glue adds damping to the vibrating coil, then the  coil's stationary response gets smaller as well as the noise produced
2. glue adds constraints to the coil, then the coil's (mechanical) fundamental frequency increases above your hearing capability.

*Another solution* that wasn't mentioned (disclaimer: I haven't read ALL the comments...), and an environmental sound one! *consists in unplugging the adapter* (that's what I do all the time with the charger for my Nokia cellphone!)

Answer (score 1):

I came to this page as I bought a new Craftsman C3 19.2 V Li-ion battery / charger which started making that whining noise as I plugged in. I came up to look for some answer, while reading it, I realized I had one or two wireless charging toothbrushes (Philips Sonicare and an Oral B) next to it. I moved the charger little away and the buzz went away.
I presume the buzz is from electromagnetic interference from these wireless charging units that gets picked up by the transformers in the charger.

Comment: Thanks, i actually had two laptop chargers next to each other and based on your feedback moving them apart did help!

Answer (score 0):

The adapter of my router was also making a high-pitched noise which was literally driving me crazy. However, I solved this quickly by wrapping it up in a piece of cloth. Now I do not hear it anymore.

Comment: Don't do this. Heat is an issue with any adapter and you are essentially insulating it so it can get hotter.