# High-pitched noise from Logitech Performance MX

Tags: mouse

I have two [Logitech Performance Mouse MX](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/performance-mouse-mx) devices - I loved using it at home so much, that I bought one for work! While they generally excel in comfort and usability, they're both a bit annoying in that I'll occasionally notice they emit a high-pitched noise when I'm moving them.

The noise is in a range similar to the electronic whine or squeal I hear from some CRT monitors or other electronics. However, I've owned and used many mice in my lifetime - optical, laser, wired, wireless; mostly Logitech, but some not - and this is the first I've ever heard such sounds from.

It seems especially odd that the sound only happens when I move the mouse. Since it's a laser mouse, which I believe has no moving parts aside from the wheel and buttons, I don't expect it should be behaving any differently in terms of noise generation whether it is moving or stationary.

Since it happens with both mice of the same model, and they appear to be functioning fine otherwise, I don't think it's a "hardware problem" per se. But it makes me wonder what makes these unique from other mice that I've owned?

In summary, the answer to a few questions would settle my concerns here:

1. What can cause this noise in a mouse like the Logitech Performance MX?
2. Is this expected behavior for these types of mice?
3. Does the noise indicate a hardware failure, or propensity towards early failure?
4. Can I do anything to reduce the noise? Will such changes impact device performance, reliability, or warranty?

As I grew accustomed to CRT whine some time ago, I believe I can also tolerate this noise in the long run. However, if there's anything I can do to reduce the noise without impacting the device's functionality or reliability - and especially if the cause of the noise is actually something that warrants concern - I'd like to know.

Comment: "performance" mouse, so I assume a very high DPI which might require a larger than normal capacitor which might explain it...

Comment: @AthomSfere According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Logitech_products#Mice), it supports 100-1500 DPI and uses a "Darkfield Laser". Logitech's [product page](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/performance-mouse-mx#specs) further specifies that the sensitivity can be adjusted in increments of 100 DPI.

Comment: Just a heads up, don't try an get new one under warranty, the place I used to work at I bought 3 of these mice, and have owned two (returned one due to above noise). All of them have this high pitched noise, however it's not an issue at work as it's generally too noisy to notice, but at home it's way to quiet, and you can hear it all the time. I just work with headphones now, until I can find a different ergonomic mouse, which is hard because this one is perfect but for the noise.

Comment: Appears to be coil whine: http://superuser.com/questions/832480/why-do-some-ac-adapters-and-power-supplies-generate-a-whining-noise-and-what-ca

Answer (score 4):

There are others who have reported the problem to Logitech. You should checkout their [support site](http://support.logitech.com/product/performance-mouse-mx). I'm only answering your last question because the others are ambiguous.

According to the Logitech Community forum, you can try this "short power drain procedure" to see if it resolves the issue. If not, contact support.

> 1. Remove the battery off the mouse.
> 2. Press and hold the left and right click buttons for 15 seconds.
> 3. Release the buttons and place the battery back properly. If
>      possible, replace the old ones with a new single AA NiMH
>      rechargeable battery.
> 4. Check if the mouse will feature the same coil noise.

[Source](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Coil-noise-from-Logitech-Performance-Mx/m-p/1025153#M48391)

Comment: This answer worked for me tonight. Problem appeared a few days ago on this 3 year old mouse. Switching the Logitech Unified receiver to a different USB port as others had recommended did not work.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who happens to come across this post, I just worked out that I was having this problem because I was using an old rechargeable battery. Replacing it with a newer one didn't completely resolve the issue, but it made the noise much higher frequency, which I now don't notice unless I hold the mouse to my ear.

Comment: +1. Might be battery voltage issues especially under load. The Performance Mouse MX is rather power-hungry for a wireless mouse (specified battery life is a mere one month) and so it might be more sensitive to input power issues than other mice.

Comment: If I use my mouse with the USB cable, the noise is much less. I'll try the solution with another battery. This should be the solution. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get rid of that irritating hiss. Now I'm 100% happy with the product.

The way I fixed it was by loosening a bit the screws at the bottom of the mouse. The screws are positioned below the sticky plastic pads so you have to remove them. After that, there are two screws on the top pad, one on the bottom and one on the side as well. If by loosening the screws a bit you don't see an improvement try carefully to take apart the whole bottom panel and put it again back with the screws a bit loosened. I have to warn you that the build quality of the pads is terrible and if you are not careful when removing your pads might not look as good as new when you reposition them but this won't hurt the aesthetics of the mouse.

I guess the source of the problem was that a component was making contact with the bottom side of the mouse which amplified its frequency.

Answer (score 1):

For me the only solution was go back to a ps/2 mouse, because most of the integrated sound devices share bus with the usb components, every time you move the mouse you listen that high pitch noise.

Answer (score -1):

My MX Master will get coil whine only moving to the left **and** only when mouse pad isn't on perfectly flat surface.

Swapping the USB receiver port seemed to work at first and a new rechargeable battery also seemed to work at first as other answers suggested. But in the end a perfectly flat surface for the mouse pad was the ultimate solution.