# Beeping laptop charger cause?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power, charger

I have a dell power adapter for my dell laptop (although it's not the original, it was ordered online, it has dell engraved on the charger). Anyway, it stopped charging the laptop, no green light, and it was making quiet beeping noises (from the charger itself). It was plugged into a plug adapter, so I tried it in a different one and now it's charging fine with no beeps.

I know it sounds like problem solved and I'm being a bit paranoid but I want to know **whether it's possible that this could be indicative of an underlying fault / cause with the charger itself. Is the charger still ok to use?**

Comment: I wouldn't expect a laptop charger to have an internal speaker, as there would generally be no reason to. While voltage under negligible load may or may not be indicative of anything, still, do you have access to a multimeter? Have you checked the output voltage of the charger?

Comment: Also, since we dislike questions seeking opinions, I edited yours slightly to try to encourage answers based more in fact and expertise than opinion. Feel free to [edit] further, but please review https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask and https://superuser.com/help/on-topic and https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask first (doing so will only take a few minutes). Thanks, and welcome!

Comment: I don't have a multimeter I'm afraid. Thanks for the edit too, I'll bear it in mind for any future posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do some AC adapters and power supplies generate a whining noise, and what can I do about it?](https://superuser.com/questions/832480/why-do-some-ac-adapters-and-power-supplies-generate-a-whining-noise-and-what-ca)

Answer (score 0):

I had one that used to beep the same way and had issues charging would charge for a few minutes then stop. Eventually it ceased to function . On using another charger it worked fine. The issue may also be your charger on your part also. Have a technician look at it if you think other wise but the best bet is save your money and try to get a replacement that is is compatible with the laptops original charger.